# On button click open an app that isinstalled on your device in android studio

Tags: android

I am making an app in android studio. in that app I  want that when i click on a button a chooser (open with) should open in that users can directly go from my to that app in my case i want  to add phone pay and google pay in that chooser plz help

Comment: You should add some more context and code to make your question more precise. This kind of ambiguous question makes difficult to find a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    
    
    Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    
            likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    
            try {
                startActivity(likeIng);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "App not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                }
            });
```

Set you like to open app package here

```
likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
```

Comment: i want to open phone pe app

Comment: @KalpeshChoudhary Update  likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android"); To 
 likeIng.setPackage("com.phonepe.app");